# Grails getWriter() has already been called for this response

Tags: grails

Whenever i call `<ut:profilePicture>` in my template.gsp that error happens. Here is my customTagLib

```
import rms.User

class userTagLib {
    def springSecurityService
    static namespace = "ut"

   def fullName = {
        User currentUser = springSecurityService.currentUser as User
        if (currentUser) {
            out << currentUser.firstName + " " + currentUser.lastName
        }
    }

    def profilePicture ={
        User currentUser = springSecurityService.currentUser as User
        if (currentUser){
                response.outputStream << currentUser.picture
        }
    }
}
```

Do i need to post the gsp code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing HTML and picture. You cannot just put binary image inside HTML, HTML should contain only a link to the image instead.

You can make a Controller with Action for profile pictures, like:

```
def picture() {
    User user = User.get(params.id)
    response.contentType = ... // image/jpeg i guess?
    response.outputStream << user.picture
    return null
}
```

and put a link inside a tag:

```
def profilePicture ={
    User currentUser = springSecurityService.currentUser as User
    if (currentUser){
        out << '<img src="'
        out << createLink(controller: 'user', action: 'profile', id: currentUser.id)
        out << '" alt="" />'
    }
}
```

Comment: but wont the tag if used in a gsp output the link and wont display the actual picture?

Comment: `createLink(controller: 'user', action: 'profile', id: currentUser.id)` I tried this and `createLink` is underscored and the output is `/myProject/admin/picture/2`

Comment: sorry, was confused, you need a IMG tag with this link. but you got the idea, right?

Comment: something like this? `<img src="<ut:profilePicture/>">` It makes an error though `Attribute value quote wasn't closed (uri="<ut:profilePicture)`